# Advent of code - Stuck on Day 1 Part two problems

Tags: typescript

I really are desperate here, I'm participate in advent of code 2023 - https://adventofcode.com/ and now I'm stuck in Day 1 - Part 2 problems. Here's the requirement they will give you the data set something like this

```
const testString: string[] = [
    "two1nine",
    "eightwothree",
    "abcone2threexyz",
    "xtwone3four",
    "4nineeightseven2",
    "zoneight234",
    "7pqrstsixteen",
  ];
```

Your task is to extract the first and last digits then calibrate them and summing this for final answer so in this example, the calibration values are 29, 83, 13, 24, 42, 14, and 76. Adding these together produces 281. Also in part two letters "one", "two", "three",... are also count as digits.

Here's my code

```
const partTwo = () => {
  const testString: string[] = [
    "two1nine",
    "eightwothree",
    "abcone2threexyz",
    "xtwone3four",
    "4nineeightseven2",
    "zoneight234",
    "7pqrstsixteen",
  ];

  const filePath = "data.txt";
  const dataArray: string[] = fs
    .readFileSync(filePath)
    .toString()
    .split("\n")
    .map((str: string) => str.replace("\r", ""));

  const numberMapping: Map<string, number> = new Map([
    ["one", 1],
    ["two", 2],
    ["three", 3],
    ["four", 4],
    ["five", 5],
    ["six", 6],
    ["seven", 7],
    ["eight", 8],
    ["nine", 9],
  ]);

  const convertToInteger = (str: string): number => {
    const regexPattern = Array.from(numberMapping.keys()).join("|") + "|\\d";
    const regex = new RegExp(regexPattern, "g");
    const foundWords = str.match(regex);

    if (!foundWords || foundWords.length === 0) return 0;

    console.log(foundWords);

    const first = isNaN(parseInt(foundWords[0]))
      ? numberMapping.get(foundWords[0])
      : parseInt(foundWords[0]);
    const last = isNaN(parseInt(foundWords[foundWords.length - 1]))
      ? numberMapping.get(foundWords[foundWords.length - 1])
      : parseInt(foundWords[foundWords.length - 1]);

    return (first ?? 0) * 10 + (last ?? 0);
  };

  const getTotalSum = (arr: number[]) => {
    return arr.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr, 0);
  }

  const result = dataArray.map((str) => convertToInteger(str));
  const resultNumber = getTotalSum(result);

  const resultMap: Record<string, number> = {};
  dataArray.forEach((str) => {
    resultMap[str] = convertToInteger(str);
  });

  result.forEach((str, i) => console.log(`${dataArray[i]} - ${str}`));
  console.log(result);
  console.log(resultNumber);
};
```

The problems here is that I couldn't find where the possible errors could be. Using the test data I've provided above got the right answers. But using the inputs here - https://adventofcode.com/2023/day/1/input which I got the sum of calibration values of 54489 which is the wrong answer. Here're the fraction of the result data I have

```
2qlljdqcbeight - 28
eight47srvbfive - 85
slconeightfoureight557m38 - 18
xvqeightwosixnine61eightsn2tdczfhx - 82
msixonexch1twokjbdlhchqk1 - 61
112ninejlhhjmjzkzgdsix - 16
6six7jr - 67
878eightgvsqvzfthree - 83
2jxzhlkhdktxfjjleightdfpgfxjv - 28
mxbzgzg5three - 53
33fivehcxcxhsqhtwo - 32
bhfive4ths1811seven - 57
eightfxkpsqjlpjgjcp12twoxkhllqzq7 - 87
sixkvvhvgtcnjhjtmxnr7seven8 - 68
csdeightwobtsxflml4eightbxbzmvhq2four - 84
twoplpbhq3mkkhb2 - 22
1sevenrsgrl76rqtsqqzkncrgznine - 19
6twolnlq - 62
nine567 - 97
qjvhrrtdqgsp8pxrlslvtwothree9three3 - 83
ninekxpninedjx7phcncpzq - 97
onegmzclftbt8sixmkfnqpeight - 18
one53foureightzpvseven9 - 19
315foursixonefcvttgrknrgf1 - 31
and more...
```

Can you help me point out the possible area of error here? Please help!

Comment: Could it be your map only includes words for 1 - 9 ? what is it suppose to do with :
"7pqrstsixteen"  as  sixteen isn't on the list.

Comment: Ah, the result only contain 0-9 digits. But I think I've found the possible error. The case "44-mnbrf3fourfpbrdgltf2xbmbmrbjltdxbklsixoneightq" instead of 48 I got 41 instead. I think it's because the regex are overlapped "oneight" should match "one" and "eight" but instead got only "one". Have any ideas how should I fix this?

Comment: Oh I see, they didn't want you to get sixteen, they only wanted the 6 that was found.  I'm not sure in regex format, but obviously if its stopping on the "one" and not going to the last found value, then there is an issue with that.  Find out why its stopping early and not finding the next value.  Could you use tools to count the length of the string, the amount of found numbers, and perhaps when you know the length you can start go backwards from that location and find the last value.

Comment: I'd avoid regex and "fancy stuff" on this problem. Just iterate step by step looking for the first prefix. Regex and replacements lead to a world of overlaps, ordering, tears, hurt and edge cases.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at line 262 of the input: `oneseventwotwothreemr4dfkjlgshjzvlxqqoneightvvr`

Near the end of the line there is `oneight`. Using your regex `/one|...|eight/g` (shortened for simplicity) will result in `one` getting matched, but now it begins matching from after `one`, resulting in `ight` which fails the check.

A simple fix to this would be to use regex lookaheads like so: `/(o(?=ne))|...|(e(?=ight))/g` will match `one` then begin matching from after the `o`. The only problem is that `match()` will now only return the first letter of the number matched instead of the whole word.

As a workaround you could use `matchAll()` to get the indices of each number, then do a second pass using the original regex to get the full word